# ng-repeat with tables not working

Tags: html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a fairly new web developer, just needed quick help with some view code.

I was looping through an object in my controller called "products".  I was displaying all the data of each item fine before I wanted to organize it in a table.

Could anyone see the problem with my code? I'm a very weak front end designer, back end is my niche, so it could be a very simple error.

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in Ctrl.products">
    <td><img ng-src= "{{product.image}}"></td>
    <td>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td><td>{{product.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td><td>{{product.price}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {{product.description}}
        </tr>
    </td>           
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a TR inside a TD. You need to insert a full table inside the TD to achieve what you want.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <table><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowspan properties:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="product in Ctrl.products">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><img ng-src= "{{product.image}}"></td>
            <td>Name:</td><td>{{product.name}}</td>
            <td rowspan="2">{{product.description}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price:</td><td>{{product.price}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```